# UIImageに影付き文字を挿入する方法について

Tags: swift, ios, swift3, uiimage, ios10

お世話になります。
iOSアプリでUIImageに直接文字を書き入れるような動作があるアプリを製作中なのですが、その文字に影をいれようとしたところ、上手く動作しませんでした。
文字列の背景色を設定するオプションなどは正常に動作します。

上記問題を解決するには、どのような方法があるでしょうか。
何卒、ご協力ください。

開発環境は

- Xcode 8.3.3
- Swift 3.1
- iPhone6s(iOS10.1.1), iPhone6Plus(10.2.1)

です。

ソースコード及び引数、返却値は下記の通りです。

引数

- text:String 描画する文字列です。
- image:UIImage この画像に文字列を描画します。

返却値

- newImage ここに文字描画後の画像を代入することが目的となります。

ソース

```
    let font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)

    let imageWidth = image.size.width
    let imageHeight = image.size.height

    let rect = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:imageWidth, height:imageHeight)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, false, 0)

    image.draw(in: rect)

    let textRect  = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:imageWidth, height:imageHeight)
    let textStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.default.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle

    let shadow = NSShadow()
    shadow.shadowColor = UIColor.red
    shadow.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 50, height: 30)
    shadow.shadowBlurRadius = 1

    let textFontAttributes = [
        NSFontAttributeName: font,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black,
        NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: textStyle,
        NSShadowAttributeName:shadow
    ]

    text.draw(in: textRect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Comment: 追記：上記コードで半角英数字は正常に影が描画できるのを確認しました。全角文字が含まれている場合に描画できなくなる模様です。

Comment: 私の環境では正しく動いてるように見えます。「上手く動作しません」というのは具体的にどのような問題が起こっていますか？

Comment: ご連絡ありがとうございます。上手く動作しない、というのは文字自体の描画はなされているが、影が一切描画されていない状態になる、ということです。

Comment: 私の環境では影も描画されてますね。気になるところといえば`shadowOffset`の指定が大きすぎるように思えますが、試しに5ポイントくらいの数字に変えてみたらどうなりますか？

Comment: おっしゃる通りオフセット値は大きい値であったため修正いたしました。しかし、shadowOffset値に限らず、やはり全角文字は影が描画されていないままです。

Answer (score 1):

原因はよく分かりませんが、コメントに記載の条件「全角文字が含まれている場合」に(このような条件については、コメントだけでなくご質問本文に含めるようにお願いします)影の部分が描画されなくなるという現象はこちらでも確認(Xcode 8.3.3のPlayground上)できました。

(ちなみにXcode 9 GM seedでは、あなたのコードをSwift 4での修正に合わせるだけで、日本語を含む文字列にも影がつきました。)

もちろん特定条件で一部の属性が無効になるという記述はドキュメントにはありませんので、単純にバグとして[Appleに報告](http://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/)した方が良いように思われます。

さて、 ***上記問題を解決するには、どのような方法があるでしょうか*** と言うのがご質問のお題のようなので、(原因をあれこれ考えるのは早々にあきらめて)私の環境ではこれでうまくいったというコードを掲載しておきます。

```
let font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)

let imageWidth = image.size.width
let imageHeight = image.size.height

let rect = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:imageWidth, height:imageHeight)

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, false, 0)

image.draw(in: rect)

let textRect  = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:imageWidth, height:imageHeight)
let textStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.default.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle

let shadow = NSShadow()
shadow.shadowColor = UIColor.red
shadow.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5, height: 3)
shadow.shadowBlurRadius = 3

let textFontAttributes = [
    NSFontAttributeName: font,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black,
    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: textStyle,
    NSShadowAttributeName:shadow
]

let attrText = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: textFontAttributes)
attrText.draw(in: textRect)

let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

あなたのコードとの違いは、`String`の(あるいは`NSString`の)`draw(in:withAttributes:)`メソッドを呼ぶのではなく、`NSAttributedString`をまず作成し、その`draw(in:)`メソッドを呼んでいるという点です。

ビルド環境の問題なのか実行環境の問題なのかも調べられていないのですが、そちらの環境ではどのような結果になりますでしょうか。お試しください。